# Hiding rows from gridview based on a value from field in that row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view and in this grid some rows have a field called "Department". What I want is a code that reads that fields value and then if it equals a string "Industrial" the row should be hidden and not shown.

I tried:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.Cells[4].Text == "industrial")
        e.Row.Visible = false; 
}
```

But it keeps saying (e) is not defined, and there is no such thing as (.Row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [`GridViewRowEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewroweventargs.row(v=vs.110).aspx) that have access to `e.Row` but it's used in `RowCreated` and `RowDataBound` events. You can use `SelectedRow` property of `GridView` instead.

```
var gridView = (GridView)sender;

if (gridView.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text == "industrial")
    gridView.SelectedRow.Visible = false;
```

**Updated:**

To hide the rows when page is loaded, place the `for` loop inside the `Page_Load` event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text == "industrial")
            GridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: so it did work but the thing is i want the row to be hidden when the page starts not when i select the row, thanks for the help

Comment: thanks, it worked perfectly :D 

thank you for helping :)